# Separating ("high enough") trees from "lower height" vegetation? In abstract (non-RGB) .xyz point cloud

Tags: 3d, clustering, point-cloud

Suppose I want to select trees that are "high enough", but the data contains other vegetation, like bushes and smaller trees.

My data is abstract (non-RGB) .xyz point cloud. I.e. there's only coordinates, no colors etc.

Consider as an example a "North European" forest, so e.g. like:

[Forest Example Picture](https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-Bp4rF_BVb5s/XcGsCic6XkI/AAAAAAAAMjM/v3_YGc0lZiYzsWaBnSqnQ_1Mw0q3EJv5wCLcBGAsYHQ/s1600/57624524.jpg)

How do I approach it?

Naive idea:

- filter based on height/Z-value, i.e. discard points that are "below" some value.

  - **Problem:** If I filter and discover what points belong to "high trees", then how can I recover the "lower part" of those trees? To e.g. know the height of the tree?

Other ideas:

- Classify in "3D k-nearest" sense to first group points that belong to a certain plant. This could allow me have point classes: bushes, trees, ... And I could remove point classes.

  - **Problem**: To know, which kind of classification works "consistently" for different inputs.
- Some more advanced clustering algo, but ATM I'm not sure, which "view on clustering" would be most suitable for differentiating vegetation. E.g. density-based or something else.
- A combination of different approaches. E.g.

  - Use naive "filter by height" to find some points belonging to higher trees.
  - Find some of these points from the cloud prior to the naive filter and do some clustering using these points as "anchor points". So that the clustering algo wouldn't have to care about other points than those related to the higher trees.

---

I'm currently using Python and `pdal` library. I've tried `filters.cluster` with varying parameters and it seems "decent", but it's not a very detailed implementation. I have hard time understanding what clusters to retain and what not.

This experimenting has suggested that I might also try doing several runs of the clustering, each getting rid of something, until my data is "clean" enough to cluster individual trees even.

I'm open to any tool, but this question is geared more towards identifying "theoretically suitable" approaches. Rather than, implementation-specific.

Comment: What have you tried?. Which software and are you open to scripting by yourself?

Comment: What kind of forest? Coniferous trees with one apex are easier. Trees with flat canopies or multiple apices will be difficult.Take a look at FUSION. Here is the manual: http://forsys.cfr.washington.edu/Software/FUSION/FUSION_manual.pdf

Comment: @Albert North European (and it could even serve as an example). So e.g. like: https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-Bp4rF_BVb5s/XcGsCic6XkI/AAAAAAAAMjM/v3_YGc0lZiYzsWaBnSqnQ_1Mw0q3EJv5wCLcBGAsYHQ/s1600/57624524.jpg

Comment: In this example the highest trees look like some kind of abies that will be very easy to spot from FUSION. Using CanopyMaxima you will be able to create a point layer with the information of height and the perimeter of points associated with it.